# Is there a way to listen to process?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process

I want to know if there is a way to listen to a process in Linux & unix - when it ends and what's the exit code of the process(script).

I don't want to write a script that will run `X` seconds and check by `ps -ef | grep PID` if the process is still alive. I want to know if there is a way that the process will notify me when it ended and what was its exit code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash does this for you. It will notify you when the process ends by giving you back control and it will store the exit status in the special variable `$?`. It look roughly like this:

```
someprocess
echo $?
```

See the [bash manual about special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) for more information.

But I asume that you want to do other work while waiting. In bash you can do that like this:

```
someprocess &
otherwork
wait %+
echo $?
```

`someprocess &` will start the process in the background. That means control will return immediately and you can do other work. A process started in the background is called a job in bash. `wait` will wait for the given job to finish and then return the exit status of that job. Jobs are referenced by `%n`. `%+` refers to the last job started. See the [bash manual about job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) for more information.

If you really need the PID you can also do it like this:

```
someprocess &
PID=$!
otherwork
wait $PID
echo $?
```

`$!` is a special variable containing the PID of the last started background process.

Comment: And how does `wait` works? How much CPU it will typically take from the system?

Comment: I do not know how exactly bash `wait` works. I do know that it does not take noticeable amount of system resources. You can review the source code here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/wait.def

Answer (score 8):

One -- admittedly heavy-handed -- approach is to use `strace`:

```
$ strace -e trace=none -e signal=none -p 12345
```

will watch the process with PID 12345, intercepting no system call (first `-e`) and no signals (second `-e`). Once the process exits in a regular way, the exit value will be printed.

If the process is terminated by a signal, strace exits silently (when run with the options given above). You can use e.g. `-e signal=kill` to change this behaviour. Note, however, that `-e signal=all` (or, equivalently, omitting the `-e signal` option) might produce a large amount of output if signals are received and handled by the program.

Answer (score 4):

1. Chaining the execution of "notify"

   ```
   $ process; notify $? &
   ```

   Notice that if the process will exit in unexpected way `notify` won't be executed
2. Setting up traps

   Process is signalled by signals of a different meaning and can react appropriately

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   process

   function finish {
       notify $?
   }
   trap finish EXIT
   ```

You are not clear what notification you have in mind. In essence it can be anything what rings a "bell" of course. One for many eg. `notify-send` from `libnotify` library.

```
$ process; notify-send "process finished with status $?" &
```

Answer (score 2):

if your process run as deamon, consider using upstart or monit, they are kind of standard ways:

http://www.alexreisner.com/code/upstart

http://mmonit.com/monit/

They can monitor process, exit code, restart processes, write log, ...

Answer (score 1):

With `ptrace()` you can attach a tracer to a process (or run a new one), set an *hook* with `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT` (linux >= 2.5.60) and sleep until the process exit, then with `PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG` get the exit status.

Here a sample implementation called [stopper](http://www.technovelty.org/linux/stopping-at-program-at-exit.html), I checked it with the `attach` option only and it required some few changes to get it working (eventually if needed I'll post the code somewhere).